# DTD. Element Type Declaration. Different between 'contentspec' and 'content model'

Tags: xml, dtd, sgml

I read [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition) W3C Recommendation 26 November 2008](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-contentspec)

**3.2 Element Type Declarations** has:
 An element type declaration takes the form:
Element Type Declaration

```
elementdecl ::= <!ELEMENT Name contentspec >
contentspec ::= 'EMPTY' | 'ANY' | Mixed | children
```

And in **3.2.1 Element Content** has:
Element-content Models

```
children ::= (choice | seq) ('?' | '*' | '+')?
cp ::= (Name | choice | seq) ('?' | '*' | '+')?
choice ::= '(' S? cp ( S? '|' S? cp )+ S? ')'
 seq ::=    '(' S? cp ( S? ',' S? cp )* S? ')'
```

After it I had question. Which different between 'contentspec' and 'content model'.

Maybe
**contentspec** is ANY, PCDATA, Mixed, *children*.

And only *children* has '**content model**': (elemName1 | elemName2, elemName3, elemET).

(Name | , '?' '*' '+'), sequence, choice - all that is '**content model**'. Right?

Does *Mixed* have '**content model**'?

In tutorial write often:

```
<!ELEMENT Name content_model >
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it.

> **contentspec** is ANY, PCDATA, Mixed, children.
>   And only children has 'content model'

It describes all the types of content an element can have:

- `EMPTY` tag -- no content
- `ANY` any other elements defined in the DTD -- kind of free-form
- *Mixed content*, which is decribed in 3.2.2 of the XML recommendation
- *children*, which is described in 3.1.1 of the XML recommendation

*Content model* allows to use sequence, choice, parenthis and so on, e.g. `((a|b)|(c+, d?, e*))?`, and only reference others elements -- `#PCDATA` is not allowed here.

*Mixed content* is a bit particular since this model can **only** use choice, and therefore is distinct to **content model**. A mixed content is either `#PCDATA` or something like `(#PCDATA | a | b | c)*`. In the latter case you need to open an parenthesis `(`, `#PCDATA` must come first, then you specify the allowed elements separated by the choice `|` and finish by closing the parenthesis `)`, with the *zero or more* occurence specifier `*`.

The consequence of all this is provided in **3.2.2 Mixed content** :

> In this case, the types of the child elements may be constrained, but not their order or their number of occurrences

In particular, it won't be possible to define an element:

- that can contain either text (`#PCDATA`) or a sequence of elements: e.g. (`#PCDATA`) | (a, b, c)) is not valid
- that must start with an element, followed by text, then other element: e.g. `(a, #PCDATA;, b, c)` is also not valid

You can not also be ensured that your element in your XML instance will have any content at all (it can remain empty).