# How to define dtd element with XOR

Tags: xml, dtd

I have an xml element *vehicle* that can have as sub-elements either *car* XOR *truck* XOR a combination of multiple #PCDATA OR *bus*. How do I write the dtd?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!ELEMENT root (vehicle)*>
    <!ELEMENT vehicle (truck|car|(#PCDATA|bus)*)>
```

The above fails with error

> parser error : ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in XML. Once you need to define a content model allowing text (`#PCDATA`) and elements - also named *mixed content* - , you **MUST** define it that way :

```
(#PCDATA | element1 | element2 | ...)*
```

A workaround for your case can probably be :

```
<!ELEMENT vehicle (truck|car|buscontent)>
<!ELEMENT buscontent (#PCDATA | bus)* >
```

Comment: this is exactly what I ended up doing just after posting the question :)

Comment: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960711/can-there-be-text-and-additional-nodes-in-xml/29960968#29960968) I answered to, you will also find the references regarding *mixed content*. This [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389351/dtd-element-type-declaration-different-between-contentspec-and-content-mode) as well is around the subject.